# Open sub and sub-submenu on click

Tags: jquery

My javascript working well with submenu, but not with sub-submenu: it should be hidden until i click "Season", then it opens (slides down) under parent item.

html & javascript:

```js
$('#main-menu > ul > li:has(.dropdown-menu)').addClass('sub').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).parents('ul.dropdown-menu').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});

$('#main-menu > ul > ul > li:has(.dropdown-menu-2)').addClass('sub').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).parents('ul.dropdown-menu-2').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/">Information</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/toitlustus">Season</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu-2">
            <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/toitlustus">Winter</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/majutus">Spring</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/majutus">Food</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/meist/">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Take a look [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/jawamqao/)

**UPDATE:** common quys, we are almost there, we only need to find out, why `.find('a')` (take a look LinkinTED solution) affects all anchors, not only "information" and "seasons"! Please!

Comment: your css selector with 'ul > ul' in it fails. 'ul > li > ul' would be better ;-)

Comment: Change `$(this).find('ul').slideToggle();` to `$(this).children('ul').slideToggle();`. However your code still needs some love. When clicking 'seasons' it closes the first level submenu instead of opening the second level submenu

Answer (score 0):

Using `find('ul')` will trigger **all** lists inside the element.

So instead, use `children('ul')`.

Further, clicking 'seasons' closes the first level submenu instead of opening the second level submenu. You can fix that by binding the click event on the `a`.

```
$('#main-menu > ul > li:has(.dropdown-menu)').addClass('sub').find('a').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).parents('ul.dropdown-menu').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle();
});

$('#main-menu > ul > ul > li:has(.dropdown-menu-2)').addClass('sub').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).parents('ul.dropdown-menu-2').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/jawamqao/12/)

Comment: When i click "seasons", it doesn't open the submenu in your solution...

Comment: you are right, it opens with firefox and edge, but does'nt with my chrome, hmm... secondly, clicking "winter" and "spring" doesn't redirect anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

there was a little mistake in LinkinTED code - he should add `.find('a')` into second part of a code as well:

```
$('#main-menu > ul > li > ul > li:has(.dropdown-menu-2)').addClass('sub-sub').find('a').on('click', function(event)....
```

now it's perfect! thank you!